# Get Selected value from Multi-Value Select Boxes by jquery-select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 Jquery to  bind  my dropdown  which  is  used  for  multiple   selection . I  am  using  select2 jquery.

It's  working  fine,  I  can bind  my  dropdown but I  need  to get  the selected  value from my multi-value selector. I am looking for  method  to get  value  which  is  supported  by  select2 Jquery.  it  might  be  having  a  function  get  selected  value.
my drop  down  binding  code

```
$(".leaderMultiSelctdropdown").select2( {
    maximumSelectionSize: 4
});
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
alert("Selected value is: "+$(".leaderMultiSelctdropdown").select2("val"));
```

alternatively, if you used a regular selectbox as base, you should be able to use the normal jquery call, too:

```
alert("Selected value is: "+$(".leaderMultiSelctdropdown").val());
```

both return an array of the selected keys.

Comment: Thanks  a  lot  @manuFS  ,  can  you  tell  me  how  to  set  selected  value   to   multi-value  selecter..  i  know  this  is  another  question but  if  you  can.

Comment: >> http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/ `$(".leaderMultiSelctdropdown").select2("val", ["some","keys"]);`

Comment: yours   second  one  is  not returning  the  value  ...any    how     first  is  working  so  thats   gud  for  me.

Comment: the second one will set the value to "some" and "keys", not return it.

Comment: see  this  link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889552/how-to-set-selected-value-in-multi-value-select-in-jquery-select2

Comment: what   i    used  for  key  and  some?

Answer (score 40):

I know its late but I think you can try like this

```
$("#multipledpdwn").on("select2:select select2:unselect", function (e) {

    //this returns all the selected item
    var items= $(this).val();       

    //Gets the last selected item
    var lastSelectedItem = e.params.data.id;

})
```

Hope it may help some one in future.

Answer (score 28):

### Returns the selected data in structure of object:

```
console.log($(".leaderMultiSelctdropdown").select2('data'));
```

Something like:

```
   [{id:"1",text:"Text",disabled:false,selected:true},{id:"2",text:"Text2",disabled:false,selected:true}]
```

### Returns the selected val:

```
console.log($('.leaderMultiSelctdropdown').val());
console.log($('.leaderMultiSelctdropdown').select2("val"));
```

Something like:

```
["1", "2"]
```

Answer (score 11):

Simply :

```
$(".leaderMultiSelctdropdown").val()
```

Answer (score 9):

Try like this,

```
jQuery('.leaderMultiSelctdropdown').select2('data');
```

Comment: The currently accepted answer did not work for me - it just gave `["1","2"]`, etc. no matter what I picked.  This one gave the correct info for me.

Answer (score 4):

**You should try this code.**

```
 $("#multiple_Package_Ids_checkboxes").on('change', function (e) { 
        var totAmt = 0;
        $.each($(this).find(":selected"), function (i, item) { 
            totAmt += $(item).data("price");
            });
        $("#PackTotAmt").text(totAmt);
    });
```

Comment: it is useful solution for multiple selected option.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, in my opinion. Actually it's for numbers, but you can easily use for text.

Comment: This right here is the right answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $('.select').on('select2:selecting select2:unselecting', function(e) {

      var value = e.params.args.data.id;

  });
```

Comment: You might want to expand a bit on why this answer is different from the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

Please, ckeck this simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/521/). You can get values in **select2 multi**.

```
var values = $('#id-select2-multi').val();
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score -3):

This will get selected value from multi-value select boxes:
    $("#id option:selected").val()