# How to Set Selected value in Multi-Value Select in Jquery-Select2.?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am  binding  my  dropdown  with `Jquery-Select2`.  It's  working  fine  but  now  I  need  to  bind  my  Multi-Value  `selectBox`   by  using `Jquery-Select2`.

My DropDown

```html
<div class="divright">
  <select
    id="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations"
    class="leaderMultiSelctdropdown Books_Illustrations"
    name="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations"
    multiple=""
  >
    <option value=" ">No illustrations</option>
    <option value="a">Illustrations</option>
    <option value="b">Maps</option>
    <option value="c">Portraits</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

From   this  link  http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/     I am  using  Multiple  Value  Select  Box,  I  can  bind  my  dropdown  with

```js
$("dropdownid").Select2()
```

Its  working  fine,  but  now  I  need  to  get  that  selected  value  into  my  dropdown  on  edit  mode So  I am  using  this  example:

```js
$(".Books_Illustrations").select2("val", ["a", "c"]);
```

It's  working  but  how   can I  fix  my  choice,  because  user  can  choose  anything.  So  I  can't  write  a,c   statically  that's  why  I  need  to  bind  my  Selected  value  on  Edit  mode  dynamically.

I  think  now  you  all  are  clear  with  my  requirements.  Please  let  me  know  if  you  need  further  clearance.

Comment: you need all the selected value in a text box ?

Comment: i  need  my Multi-value  shows  My  Selected  value  on  Edit  mode

Comment: can you explain me i think i can help you

Comment: you need all the selected value in a text box or in a text area where the user can edit right

Comment: its  like that  ,  but  i  am  using  dropdown  not  textbox,  actually  Select2  convert  into   as  like  textbox

Comment: i can't understand tell me clearly

Comment: @S Varun  ... see  this  link  http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: and  please  check  i  have  edit  my  question

Comment: It's still not very clear what you want to achieve

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NdQbw/2/   see  this  link  i  need  to  set  that  value  on  my  dropdwon

Comment: you need initializer the select2 with all items? http://jsfiddle.net/jRSsn/

Comment: @iJD yes   its  almost  like  that  i  need  only  selected  item  which  are  select  by  user  on create  mode  ?

Comment: how the user select? it do **"select2"** .Or the user select out the **"select2"** from another code. i dont know what you mean

Comment: it  means  your  list  have  6 records  and  your  has  choose  3 records  so  i want  display  that  3 records  as  selected  along  with  other  remaining  as  unselected ...Now  you  can  understand  better

Comment: @KapsHasija Still require more explanation kapil sir........

Comment: @Visions   Do  you  know  me?

Comment: @iJD   see this  link  http://jsfiddle.net/NdQbw/4/   ..  thsi  is  working  fine  but i need  with  Select2.  this  is  simple  multiselection.

Comment: @KapsHasija yes.... come in jquery chat room ram here..

Comment: @KapsHasija when you get the values always return a,c because you use the class selector and it get the first one found. [See_this] (http://jsfiddle.net/jRSsn/)

Comment: @KapsHasija http://jsfiddle.net/NdQbw/5/

Comment: @IJD  i have  updated  your  code   for  acc.  to  my  req.  Any how  Your  code  is  really  good,  i appreciate  you  Thankuu  Very  Much.http://jsfiddle.net/jRSsn/1/

Comment: So  please  make  as  answer  so  i can  give  you bounty..Thanks

Comment: select2 V4.0.3 To set multiple default selections: [this is the way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37918749/219112)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Well actually your only need $.each to get all values, it will help you  [jsfiddle.net/NdQbw/5](http://jsfiddle.net/NdQbw/5)

```
<div class="divright">
            <select id="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations" class="leaderMultiSelctdropdown Books_Illustrations" name="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations" multiple="">
                <option value=" ">No illustrations</option>
                <option value="a" selected>Illustrations</option>
                <option value="b">Maps</option>
                <option value="c" selected>selectedPortraits</option>
            </select>
    </div>

<div class="divright">
        <select id="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations1" class=" Books_Illustrations" name="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations" multiple="">
            <option value=" ">No illustrations</option>
            <option value="a">Illustrations</option>
            <option value="b">Maps</option>
            <option value="c">selectedPortraits</option>
        </select>
</div>

<button class="getValue">Get Value</button>
<button  class="setValue"> Set  value </button>

<div class="divright">
        <select id="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations2" class="leaderMultiSelctdropdown Books_Illustrations" name="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations" multiple="">
            <option value=" ">No illustrations</option>
            <option value="a" selected>Illustrations</option>
            <option value="b">Maps</option>
            <option value="c" selected>selectedPortraits</option>
        </select>
</div>

<div class="divright">
        <select id="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations3" class=" Books_Illustrations" name="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations" multiple="">
            <option value=" ">No illustrations</option>
            <option value="a">Illustrations</option>
            <option value="b">Maps</option>
            <option value="c">selectedPortraits</option>
        </select>
</div>

<button class="getValue1">Get Value</button>
<button  class="setValue1"> Set  value </button>
```

The script:

```
 var selectedValues = new Array();
    selectedValues[0] = "a";
    selectedValues[1] = "c";

$(".getValue").click(function() {
    alert($(".leaderMultiSelctdropdown").val());
});
$(".setValue").click(function() {
   $(".Books_Illustrations").val(selectedValues);
});

$('#drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations2, #drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations3').select2();


$(".getValue1").click(function() {
    alert($(".leaderMultiSelctdropdown").val());
});

$(".setValue1").click(function() {
    //You need a id for set values
    $.each($(".Books_Illustrations"), function(){
            $(this).select2('val', selectedValues);
    });
});
```

Comment: actually  thing  is   that  we are  getting  value  as  a  string  not  as  a array  so  thats  why  i  am using  contain   check  to filter  only  selected  value

Answer (score 57):

I get this post is old but there have been changes to how select2 works now and the answer to this question is extremely simple.

To set the values in a multi select2 is as follows

```
$('#Books_Illustrations').val([1,2,3]).change();
```

There is no need to specify `.select2` in jquery anymore, simply `.val`

Also there will be times you will not want to fire the `change` event because you might have some other code that will execute which is what will happen if you use the method above so to get around that you can change the value without firing the `change` event like so

```
$('#Books_Illustrations').select2([1,2,3], null, false);
```

If that does not work you can also do this to not trigger the change event

```
$('#Books_Illustrations').select2();
$('#Books_Illustrations').val('some_value');
```

Answer (score 23):

So I take it you want 2 options default selected, and then get the value of it? If so:

http://jsfiddle.net/NdQbw/1/

```
<div class="divright">
    <select id="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations" class="leaderMultiSelctdropdown Books_Illustrations" name="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations" multiple="">
        <option value=" ">No illustrations</option>
        <option value="a" selected>Illustrations</option>
        <option value="b">Maps</option>
        <option value="c" selected>selectedPortraits</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And to get value:

```
alert($(".leaderMultiSelctdropdown").val());
```

To set the value:

```
 $(".leaderMultiSelctdropdown").val(["a", "c"]);
```

You can also use an array to set the values:

```
var selectedValues = new Array();
selectedValues[0] = "a";
selectedValues[1] = "c";

$(".Books_Illustrations").val(selectedValues);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NdQbw/4/

Comment: yes We  can  get  like  this ,  But  i  am  talking  about  Set  Selected  value on  Edit  Mode ,Note  getting  value  from  Create  Mode

Comment: Updated answer: $(".leaderMultiSelctdropdown").val(["a", "c"]);

Comment: Jaminon   your  code  is  fine   but   how  we  can   fix  that  selected  value   as  a,c   it  should  be  dynamically

Comment: Updated the answer, you can use an array for that :)

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1703902.aspx/1 check this link may be it will help you/...........

Comment: @Geert Jaminon   your   code  is  fine  but  it  is  working  with  normal  multiple  selection  box  i  need  with  Jquery Select2

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for using an array to set the multi values. It was a light to my darkness.

Answer (score 15):

Using select2 jquery library:

```
$('#selector').val(arrayOfValues).trigger('change')
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var valoresArea=VALUES
// it has the multiple values to set separated by comma
var arrayArea = valoresArea.split(',');
$('#area').select2('val',arrayArea);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it would be preferable if you could add a description as to why your code block solves the issue. This is a suggestion to improve this and future answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
This is with reference to the original question
$('select').val(['a','c']);
$('select').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 4):

Just look at this one it will helps.

```
var valoresArea=VALUES // it has the multiple values to set, separated by comma
var arrayArea = valoresArea.split(',');
$('#area').val(arrayArea);
```

the URL is- [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/setting-multiple-select)

Comment: I used this, after that I got only first value, not shows the remain values

Comment: $('#area').select2().val(arrayArea).trigger('change');

Comment: I used to like this and I am using the select2 version4. I got the result.

Answer (score 4):

you can add the selected values in an `array` and set it as the value for default selection

eg:

```
var selectedItems =[];
selectedItems.push("your selected items");
..
$('#drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations').select2('val',selectedItems );
```

Try this, this should definitely work!

Answer (score 2):

Using select2 library there are 2 ways to set the value
1. when single value is present you can pass it as string

```
$("#elementid").select2("val","valueTobeset")
```

2. when you are using select2 with multiselect option you can pass an array of the values to select2 and all those values will be set

```
var arrayOfValues = ["a","c"]
$("#elementid").select2("val",arrayOfValues)
```

remember that you can set single value on multiselect by passing an array also like this

```
var arrayOfValues = ["a"]
$("#elementid").select2("val",arrayOfValues)
```

Comment: There are some syntax error in your code. For example "." sign after select2 -  select2.("val",arrayOfValues))

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work. only one value is ever pre-selected even though both options are available in the list only the first is shown
`('#searchproject').select2('val', ['New Co-location','Expansion']);`

Answer (score 2):

Use multiselect function as below.

> `$("#drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations").val(["val1", "val2"]).trigger("change");`

Answer (score 2):

**To Select all**

```
 $('select[name=eventsFilter]').find('option').attr('selected', true);
$('select[name=eventsFilter]').select2();
```

**To UnSellect all**

```
$('select[name=eventsFilter]').find('option').attr('selected', false);
  $('select[name=eventsFilter]').select2("");
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to do so many things.
for set value using multiple select2
var selectedvalue="1,2,3"; //if first 3 products are selected.
$('#ddlProduct').val(selectedvalue);

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#area').select2().val(arrayArea).trigger('change');
```

I used to like this and I am using the select2 version4. I got the result

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(".Books_Illustrations").val(["a", "c"]).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score -5):

Use multiselect function as below.

```
$('#drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations').multiSelect('select', 'value');
```

Comment: what  about  value   shell  i  give  a,c  like  that