# Setting the value of a select2 input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am attempting to set a select2 value using jquery. This is likely a duplicate question but I have read 30 different responses on here and haven't found one that solves my problem.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="has_many_fields" data-required-has-many-fields-rows="1" id="location_account_associations"><input id="location_account_associations_attributes_0__destroy" name="location[account_associations_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false" />
<div class="has_many_fields_row countable" id="location_account_associations_attributes_0">
    <div class="form__row form__row--spreadsheet">
        <div class="form__row__body">
            <div class="form__row__field-wrapper">
                <ul class="grid grid--no-gutters">
                    <li class="grid__6 grid__x--show">
                        Account Thing
                        <input id="location_account_associations_attributes_0_ab_account_id" name="location[account_associations_attributes][0][ab_account_id]" type="hidden" value="42" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="grid__5">
                        <select class="js-select2-combobox" id="location_account_associations_attributes_0_account_id" name="location[account_associations_attributes][0][account_id]" placeholder=" " reflection="#&lt;ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x012fb5asd200e8&gt;">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="1">Orange</option>
                            <option value="2">Apple</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried multiple different approaches to get "Orange" to be selected. Note that this jQuery executes when a certain keystroke is pressed. Also, for a number of reasons, the HTML is not editable. Only the jQuery can be changed.

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
(function() {
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {

        // ignore unless CTRL + ALT/COMMAND + N was pressed
        if (!(e.keyCode == 78 && e.ctrlKey && e.altKey )) return

        jQuery('[name*="[account_associations_attributes][0]').select2("val",1);
        jQuery('[name*="[account_associations_attributes][0]').select2("val","Orange");
     })
 }())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
You can select it by select id.
Live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/10/

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {

        // ignore unless CTRL + ALT/COMMAND + N was pressed
     if (!(e.keyCode == 78 && e.ctrlKey && e.altKey )) return;
        $('#location_account_associations_attributes_0_account_id option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true)
     });
});
```

You also select it by  id and value like this:

```
 $('#location_account_associations_attributes_0_account_id option[value="1"]').prop('selected', true)
```

Comment: @Zack: did you try this?

Comment: I hadn't tried it but I just did and it wouldn't work. I edited the question to include more of the javascript... Perhaps that will help?

Comment: @Zack : press CTRL + ALT+ N then it will select orange in your select box.

Comment: Sorry, I was out to lunch. Still not working. Cannot figure out why. I will experiment around for a bit.

Comment: did you check it in live demo? press CTRL + ALT+ N

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44983/discussion-between-awlad-liton-and-zack)

Answer (score 6):

Ended up finding the solution.

```
jQuery('[name*="[account_associations_attributes][0]"]').select2('val', '1')
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Is there any solution to make multiple selection/values? For ex. value 1,2 and 5.

Comment: I have found. Like this: `select2('val', ['1','2','5'])` from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889552/how-to-set-selected-value-in-multi-value-select-in-jquery-select2

Answer (score -1):

Detecting multiple keypresses, especially with modifiers, is very tricky.

Take a look at [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655202/detect-multiple-keys-on-single-keypress-event-on-jquery) and then make sure your keypress event is generating a more basic result (something simple, like an `alert()`) before you add more complex behavior like changing the values of the dropdown, which can also be tricky depending on the browser and the dropdown itself.

Comment: Yea.... I tried that... The event is working fine. I've got like 50 other things that run on the event. This is the only one that doesn't work.