# how to select options by default from select2 list?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, multiple-select

I am using select2 jquery function. To create a drop down with multiple selections. I am able to do it.  Now I need to select  a few options from the drop down list as default data.  Can you help me?

```js
data = [{id:1,text:"abc"},{id:2,text:"qwe"},{id:3,text:"def"}]; 
 
 $("#test").select2({ theme: "bootstrap", data: dat });
 
 
 
 // select option 2 as default selected I used below code
 // but it is not working..  
   $("#test").select2("val", 2);
```

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889552/how-to-set-selected-value-in-multi-value-select-in-jquery-select2

Comment: As mentioned in this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30477163/1225070 the .select2('val') The "val" method has been deprecated and will be removed in Select2 4.1. 

You can try $('#test').val('1').trigger('change');

Comment: yes this does help... but I am not able to select multiple values in 'val' :(

Comment: did you add multiple: true ? In order to select multiple values you must add this .

Comment: @nimraasad. Glad to know you problem is solved.