# How to multi select results using Select2.js with data returned from Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a **two** dropdowns that use `Select2.js`.

The second dropdown will initiate an ajax call base on the value from the first dropdown.

Assuming that I have already the result that I needed from Ajax call, and I already know what will be the result and that is the value `1276` and `1277`.

What I want is when I click either one of the results **all the results** will be selected.

As what I read in [Neelu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889552/how-to-set-selected-value-in-multi-value-select-in-jquery-select2) this will supposed to do the trick:

```
//this code block is outside the ajax call of select2.js

$('.select-2').on('select2:select', function() {
    $('.select-2').val([1276,1277]);
    $('.select-2').trigger("change");
});
```

The result doesn't reflect in the `Select2` element but when I check the value using `.val()`, I get the result `1276` and `1277`.

What I noticed if I trigger a different event e.g. `button click` to get the value of the Select2. That's the time it will work, but when I trigger another Select2 ajax call it doesn't work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution:**

> This is because during ajax call if there are no selected `options`,
>   and there are no `option` tag generated yet, thus
>   `Select2.js` can't reflect the changes in the display even though
>   `.trigger('change')` was already set.

So the trick is, during ajax call, once you received the response create an `option` tag *(which is in my case I already knew that the response will be two value and I also want to select both of them either which I selected)* thus I create two `option` tag after ajax call:

```
//..Ajax code response....
var selectElement = $(this)[0].$element[0];
processResults: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function( k, v ) {
        selectElement.innerHTML += '<option value="'+v.id+'">'+v.text+'</option>';
    });
}
```

Then outside your ajax code:

```
$('.select-2').on('select2:select', function() {
    $('.select-2').val([1276,1277]).trigger("change");
});
```

If you want to remove both selections if you either unselect one of them, this is the trick:

```
$('.select-2').on('select2:unselect', function() {
    $('.select-2').val('').trigger("change");
    //then destroy the option tag pre-created during ajax call
    $('.select-2').empty();
});
```