# Select2 Get Selected Values

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 on some multiple selects:
HTML:

```
    <select name="lead" id="lead" class="chosen-select">
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="1">Lead 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Lead 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Lead 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Lead 4</option>
                </select>
```

Javascript:

```
    $(".chosen-select").select2({
        width: '99%',
        placeholder: 'Select'
    });
```

Pretty simple and it works. But, how do I get the selected values when the form is submitted?

EDIT:
I should have been more specific. Since I have multiple selects on the page with that class, I'm trying to use the id [ $("#lead").val() ] to get the value and that doesn't always work. Can you only use the class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889309/get-selected-value-from-multi-value-select-boxes-by-jquery-select2