# Using Select2 (multiple selections) with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, jquery-select2

I'm new to vue and have followed their 'custom directive' at http://vuejs.org/examples/select2.html.

This works well when only selecting one item, but when you're selecting multiple items it only passes the first one. I need it to pass all values selected.

I have a jsfiddle set up displaying the code which is available here. 
https://jsfiddle.net/f3kd6f14/1/

The directive is as below;

```
 Vue.directive('select', {
    twoWay: true,
    priority: 1000,

    params: ['options'],

    bind: function() {
        var self = this
        $(this.el)
                .select2({
                    data: this.params.options
                })
                .on('change', function() {
                    self.set(this.value)
                })
    },
    update: function(value) {
        $(this.el).val(value).trigger('change')
    },
    unbind: function() {
        $(this.el).off().select2('destroy')
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this.value` doesn't work like you expect when Select2 is in multiple value mode (more info here: [Get Selected value from Multi-Value Select Boxes by jquery-select2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889309/get-selected-value-from-multi-value-select-boxes-by-jquery-select2)).

Try this (working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/02rafh8p/):

```
Vue.directive('select', {
    twoWay: true,
    priority: 1000,

    params: ['options'],

    bind: function() {
        var self = this
        $(this.el)
                .select2({
                    data: this.params.options
                })
                .on('change', function() {
                    self.set($(self.el).val()) // Don't use this.value
                })
    },
    update: function(value) {
        $(this.el).val(value).trigger('change')
    },
    unbind: function() {
        $(this.el).off().select2('destroy')
    }
})

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#el',
    data: {
        selected: [], // Result is an array of values.

        roles : [
            { id: 1, text: 'hello' },
            { id: 2, text: 'what' }
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: Good answer.. now, how to specify the default selected options?

Comment: Just assign your default to `selected` rather than an empty array.

Answer (score -1):

In Vue 2, to get all select2 values onchange:

Change this:

```js
.on('change', function () {
  self.$emit('input', this.value); // Don't use this.value
});
```

To this:

```js
.on('change', function () {
  self.$emit('input', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This cause an internal infinite loop that ends freezing the app