# Get the value to select in multiple way using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select

I need help in using select multiple in Jquery using.
Here is my code in snippset

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select2').select2();
});

function edit(){
  var MC_Value = $("#MC_value").val();
  $("#the_value").val(MC_Value);//I dont know to show the value I am newbie
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="MC_value" value='"Adam","George","John"'>

<a  href="javascript:void();" onclick="edit()" class="btn btn-primary form-control"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">Edit</span>
</a>
<br>
<select type="text" class="form-control select2" id="the_value" name="the_value" multiple>
      <option value="Adam">Adam</option>
      <option value="George">George</option>
      <option value="John">John</option>
</select>
```

[image]

I am upload the image to show how i want this code run. but i am new in php and jquery. need help.
Thanks master

Comment: It might be helpfull, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889402

Comment: Also check this fiddle , if you want to set select2 values, http://jsfiddle.net/NdQbw/4/

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan i try but i cant solve my problem. but thanks for help